# How to view workspace value in larger window

Tags: octave

To view a workspace value it's displayed in 'Value' colum

[image]

Can the entire value be displayed in a single window instead of it being truncated as is in 'Workspace' window above ?

Double clicking the Workspace name does not open the associated value ina  larger window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to see variable:

- don't put semicolon after variable in `Editor` and see output in `Command Window`;
- right click on variable name in `Workspace` window, select `disp` and see output in `Command Window`.